# mhddfs+osxfuse via fstab?

Tags: mount, fstab, fuse, macfuse

I'm trying to create a virtual drive pool using [FUSE for OS X](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse) and `mhddfs`.

This command works for me:

```
sudo mhddfs /Volumes/D01,/Volumes/D12,/Volumes/D103,/Volumes/D110 /mnt/DrivePoolA -o allow_other,volname=DrivePoolA
```

However, I believe I should also be able to accomplish the same using the `mount` command, but I've had no luck. I've tried a variety of things similar to the line below. What am I missing?

```
sudo mount -t mhddfs -o allow_other,volname=DrivePoolA /Volumes/D01,/Volumes/D12,/Volumes/D103,/Volumes/D110
```

Finally, and most importantly, I'm trying to mount the `drivePool` with `fstab`. My `fstab` looks like this:

```
# <file system>  <mount point> <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>  
mhddfs#/Volumes/D01,/Volumes/D12/,/Volumes/D103/,/Volumes/D110    /mnt/DrivePoolA    osxfusefs    allow_other,volname=DrivePoolA 0 0`
```

However, when I run `sudo mount -a` on that `fstab`, I get an error message which states:

> This program is not meant to be called directly. The OSXFUSE library calls it. Available mount options: [followed by the list of mount options]

Now, I'm assuming that that error is coming from osxfuse_mounter, because I found the text of the error in the source code of the 'support' project on github. I assume that the error is being passed through back to the `mount` program, which is spitting it back out the the command line.

I've also tried the following `fstab`, omitting the `options`, `dump`, and `pass`:

```
# <file system>  <mount point> <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>  
mhddfs#/Volumes/D01,/Volumes/D12/,/Volumes/D103/,/Volumes/D110    /mnt/DrivePoolA    osxfusefs
```

After running  `sudo mount -a` with this configuration, I get no errors, but nothing seems to happen.

Any suggestions?